# jQuery Ajax Allowed to make more than one call

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am creating a single page application. I am using ajax to set coldfusion session variables. Am I unable to call more than one ajax call with jQuery?

http://jsfiddle.net/1zka4soy/15/

If you click on the print labels button and enter a number you will see the ajax call and what it sets on the alert. The New button is set up exactly the same but for some reason does not run.

Is this an ajax rule that only lets you run it one time?

For some reason on the NEW button `$('#addDealer').on('submit', function (e) {` is not triggering?

**PrintLabel**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // What happens when a user hits the "Accept" button on the dealer form
    $(".label_accept").click(function () {
        $('#LabelMaker').modal('hide');

    });

    $('#labelForm').on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        //alert($(this).serialize());
        $.ajax({
            // the location of the CFC to run
            url: "proxy/LabelSession.cfm",
            // send a GET HTTP operation
            type: "post",
            // tell jQuery we're getting JSON back
            dataType: "json",
            // send the data to the CFC
            data: $('#labelForm').serialize(),
            // this gets the data returned on success
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                if (data !== "") {     
                    var link = "labels/DealerLabels.cfm";
                    window.open(link,'labelPDF'); 
                }
            }, 
            // this runs if an error
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                // show error
                console.log(errorThrown);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**New Button**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // What happens when a user hits the "Accept" button on the dealer form
    $(".dealer_accept").click(function(){
        $('#NewDealer').modal('hide');

    });

    $('#addDealer').on('submit', function (e) {
        alert("working");
        e.preventDefault();
        alert($(this).serialize());
        $.ajax({
            // the location of the CFC to run
            url: "proxy/NewDealerSession.cfm",
            // send a GET HTTP operation
            type: "post",
            // tell jQuery we're getting JSON back
            dataType: "json",
            // send the data to the CFC
            data: $('#addDealer').serialize(),
            // this gets the data returned on success
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            }, 
            // this runs if an error
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                // show error
                console.log(errorThrown);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!-- this is the working example -->
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary label_accept">Accept</button>

<!-- this one doesn't work because type=button -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dealer_accept">Accept</button>
```

Only a button with attribute `type` set to `submit` will trigger the `onSubmit` event on a form.

[Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1zka4soy/16/)